# PermissionSet deployment Error: Permission Query All Files depends on permission(s): Read All BackgroundOperation, Read BackgroundOperation

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, permission-sets, deployment-error

I'm getting following error while deploying source with `SFDX` into sandbox. This error happens without any changes to any permission set.

`Permission Query All Files depends on permission(s): Read All BackgroundOperation, Read BackgroundOperation`

The `deployment user` holds `System Administrator` profile and `System Administrator` has full permission (`Read, Create, Edit, Delete, View All, Modify All, View Setup, Edit Setup, Delete Setup`) on `Background Operation` object.

Really appreciate any clue/direction.

**I think this is after yesterday's `Summer '21 Major Release`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following object permissions to your permission set metadata file.

[image]

Comment: It works  `<object>Your Object Name listed in Deployment Error Message</object>`